# AJAX GET request in Rails without rendering views/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Making a `GET` request to check whether or not to send a followup `POST` request and don't need to render anything following the first request.  I'm using `render nothing: true` at the base of my controller action, so I'm not sure what's causing the `ActionView::MissingTemplate at /able_to_claim` error when I sent the request through the browser console:

```
 def able_to_claim
    role, user_id = params[:role], params[:user_id]
    if role == "Senior Editor" or role == "Admin"
      return true 
    else
      active_essays = 0
      Claim.where(:user_id => user_id).each {|claim| active_essays += 1 if Essay.find(claim.essay_id).status != "Complete"}
        if role == "Editor" and active_essays < 5
          return true
        elsif role == "Managing Editor" and active_essays < 15  
          return true
        else 
          return false 
        end 
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Route: `get '/able_to_claim' => 'users#able_to_claim'`

js file:

```
response = $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url : '/able_to_claim/?role=' + userRole + '&user_id=' + userId,
          crossDomain: true,
          contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json'
        });
```

userRole and userId defined in `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_tag "var userId = #{current_user.id};" if current_user %>
  <%= javascript_tag "var userRole = '#{current_user.role}';" if current_user %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, feel really silly.  I had no idea that `return` breaks out of the rest of the function.  With some refactoring:

```
def able_to_claim
    role, user_id = params[:role], params[:user_id]
    if role == "Senior Editor" or role == "Admin"
      can_claim = true
    else
      active_essays = User.find(user_id).essays.where.not(status: 'Complete').count
        if role == "Editor" and active_essays < 5
          can_claim = true
        elsif role == "Managing Editor" and active_essays < 15  
          can_claim = true
        else 
          can_claim = false
        end 
    end
      render json: {can_claim: can_claim}
  end
```